# NPM referencing invalid user directory path

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to start a new project, but it keeps referencing the wrong user location as seen:

```
C:\Users\Jeffrey Desktop\Documents\ServiceNow\Components>now-cli project --name @dev94659/test-project --description 'A test web component'
Created scope "x_23747_dev94659_2"

'C:\Users\Jeffrey' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

My Current User directory is this:

```
C:\Users\Jeffrey Desktop
```

Why is "C:\Users\Jeffrey" being referenced?

Comment: Ah, I remember running into a similar issue. Whatever creates the wrapper scripts for globally installed NPM packages (npm? node? the package's author?) was not quoting the paths in the script. Which version of node and npm do you have? If you try running `now` with Powershell instead of Cmd, does it work? If you run `which now` and open up the .cmd or .ps1, what is the content?

Comment: [Looks like](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/c3744baf2e4a140ada61c71fb4725804cec0f7e8/lib/build.js#L209) they're generated by npm with `cmd-shim` when `npm install` is run. I would suggest updating your npm (on windows so probably your node installation) - perhaps you're using an old, buggy version.

Comment: @cubrr - Tried powershell, still failed. https://imgur.com/a/7kEGcA1 . Then tried your other methods which should also be in the 2nd screenshot as mentioned.

Comment: `which` works in `cmd.exe`. What is your node and npm version? `node --version`, `npm --version`

Comment: @cubrr node = v12.16.1 | npm = 6.13.4

Comment: Adding this, then NPM to my path again fixed this issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/nodejs/setup-on-windows